# Cant parse pipe delimited header data into correct variable

Tags: java, parsing, substring

I have a file with data in the first row that i want to extract the data looks like

```
20200403|AS421|||FINN|
```

```
public void handleLine(String line) {
        if (line.contains(firstJobConfig.DELIMITER_PIPE)){
            headerInfo.setcreateDate(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(firstJobConfig.DELIMITER_PIPE)));
            headerInfo.setformName(line.substring(line.indexOf(firstJobConfig.DELIMITER_PIPE)));
        }
    }
}
```

I have code that pulls `20200403` into my `createDate` variable but i cant figure out how to get my `formName` to be set to `AS421`. right now its set to `|AS421|||FINN|`. i know that if i do`line.substring(9,14));` it will work but i want to start after the first pipe delimiter( `|`) and stop at the next one.

Comment: Line parsing is usually done by LineTokenizer; you don't havo to do by your own. If first line is different from the rest of the file maybe a PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper che be the right choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you're doing this:  `headerInfo.setformName(line.substring(line.indexOf(firstJobConfig.DELIMITER_PIPE)))` -> you're taking substring starting with the index equals to index where the first delimiter is and aren't specifying the end of this substring (That's why the result of the second substring is: `|AS421|||FINN|`). So the better way will be to use `line.split("\\|")` - It will return the table of 5 elements in your case: `["20200403","AS421","","","FINN"]`. And then you can do:

```
headerInfo.setcreateDate(table[0]);
headerInfo.setformName(table[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the strings like below.

Add a `+` to match one or more instances of the pipe:

```
temp.split("\\|+");
```